# Calculate the length of polylines in polygon (TSQL, Geometry)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial

I have a lot of polylines (polyline) and a polygon. Polylines can intersect with the polygon in different ways:

1. no intersection (polyline out of polygon)
2. no intersetion (polyline in a polygon)
3. one intersection (polyline starts/ends in polygon)
4. multiple intersections (polyline can for example start in polygon, go out of it and then return back inside...)

I need to calculate the total length of all polylines within the polygon. I'm using MSSQL 2016 Express version. Can it be done with just TSQL?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *Yes* - TSQL is [turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), meaning that you can implement any algorithm you want with it. It is more convenient to use than a [turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine) but (arguably) less so than, for example, C# with a fully fledged development environment.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct I guess, but not helpful in any way. Apparently I should have asked: "How can it be done?"

Comment: It was a bit tongue in cheek :) Maybe you could first attempt to implement the logic in SQL and then, if you come across some specific issue regarding the use of SQL to express such logic then ask for help on the specific issue.

Comment: :) I think 1. - 3. is not a problem, but I'm having a "logical" problem with situation 4. If I check for intesections and there are lets say four of them I dont know how to (sistematically) define which parts of the polyline are within the polygon...?

Comment: Probably best to rephrase the question as a pure geometry problem because that does not have anything to do with SQL yet?

Comment: Would STUnion function return the scope of polyline within the polygon?